# Find hosting through Bizspark program

Tags: web-hosting

I am a Bizspark owner and I am all set to launch my website but I am really confused about where to start the process for finding a hosting partner with my Bizspark membership. Since I have downloaded MicroSoft SQL Server from Bizspark website, I know I don't need a license for SQL Server.

So do I need to email some hosting companies and ask them if I can get their VPS and I can install my own copy of SQL Server?

That means, I will end up paying only for the VPS?

Comment: Yes you can install your own copy. You only pay for the VPS.

Answer (score 1):

Bizspark comes with a Visual Studio Enterprise subscription, which means you also get a $150 in [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/) (Microsoft's cloud platform) credit a month. As long as you stay within that pricing, there is no need to pay for a VPS.

Azure's pricing also includes licensing [for most products](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/licensing-faq/).

Answer (score 0):

[Pazis](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/33802/pazis) says in the comments:

> Yes you can install your own copy. You only pay for the VPS.

and the original poster indicated that that solution worked for them.